# Css style to dynamic content with jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap-3

Here is my jquery (3.1.1)/ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "pref.php",
            dataType: "text",
      data: { groupe_id: groupe_id, action: "getProducts" },
      cache: false,
            error: function(html){
                console.log(html);
            },
      success: function(html) {
                    $("#listProducts").html(html);
      }
    });
```

**The html response for #listProducts is as follow (with bootstrap css loaded before):**

```
<div class="row">  
  <div class="form-group row col-xs-4">
    <label class="col-xs-3 text-right" for="productName-72"><b>Name:</b></label>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm product-name" id="productName-72" aria-describedby="productName">
    </div>
  </div>
...
</div>
```

But there is no style applied to this part of code.

**What can I do to make it load the bootstrap.css style?**

Comment: have you included the style sheet?

Comment: Not sure what is your issue but `row > row col-xs-4` makes no sense. Maybe you can define "no style" applied. Not as you expected, or realy no style? No glowing blue border for example?

Comment: Thanks for the "row > row col-xs-4" tip. It was a mistake from my part, my code is now working. Sorry for the trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you're including the bootstrap css file, e.g :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

The dynamically added elements to the DOM should work just fine with bootstrap check the example below.

**NOTE :** No need for the extra `row` class in `form-group row col-xs-4`.

Hope this helps.

```js
$('#listProducts').append('<div class="row"><div class="form-group col-xs-4"><label class="col-xs-3 text-right" for="productName-72"><b>Name:</b></label><div class="col-xs-9"><input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm product-name" id="productName-72" aria-describedby="productName"></div></div>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div id="listProducts"></div>
```

Comment: My code is now working, it was a mistake from me. Thanks for the "row > row col-xs-4" tip.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your bootstrap css file is loaded on the page before the ajax request and the styles will automatically apply on the newly added content.

So, you dont need to "load" bootstrap(css files) for each consecutive request,
just keep the css file loaded on the page